# Windows Update Error 490

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, service-pack

I'm having some issues installing windows update on this particular Windows 7 PC. I'm trying to (for instance) install Service Pack 1, and its popping up an error saying "Element Not Found", and then marking it as failed with Error Code 490 : "Encountered an Unknown Error" (very useful).

This happens to pretty much all windows updates I've been trying to install.

So far, things I've tried:

Virus Scan

- Virus Scan
- Error Scan
- Running two different Microsoft 'ifixit' related to windows update
- Running it in safe mode
- Running the SP1 preperation tool
- Downloading SP 1 manually and running that
- Restarting
- Force shutting it down, taking out the battery and turning it on again

This problem has been ongoing for months now.

Looking at the System logs I do see a lot of errors but they aren't giving any useful information "Not avaliable"

So far nothing has worked, anything else I could try? I can't format the PC unfortunately.

Comment: Just curious, why can't you reformat? Have you tried force-shutting down (hold power button for a few seconds) and rebooting?

Comment: Because its not my machine and the owner doesn't want it to be reformatted. I have tried shutting down, restarting and pulling the battery out and the rest.

Comment: Try looking at the event logs for any useful information.

Comment: I looked at the error logs, there are a number of WindowsUpdateFailure with details "Not available". Not helpful.

Comment: Did you reset the date/time when you replaced the battery (If this is a PC/not laptop)? This would eliminate a potential issue with date (year) conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Open an elevated command prompt and enter the following. Press enter at the end of each line.

```
 net stop wuauserv
 regsvr32 wuapi.dll
 regsvr32 wuaueng.dll
 regsvr32 wucltux.dll
 regsvr32 wudriver.dll
 regsvr32 wups2.dll
 regsvr32 wups.dll
 regsvr32 wuwebv.dll
 net start wuauserv
 exit
```

After all that, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

[Repair Windows 7 with the inplace ugrade](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)

- boot into Windows
- insert the Windows DVD
- run the setup.exe
- select upgrade instead of clean install.

and try to install the Sp1 again.